# how can I Access my vps files without domain name through IP address on server with virtualhosts?

Tags: apache

I have a VPS with apache2 installed and I would like to access my file without a domain name just with the IP address.let's say my ip is 163.54.69.96 
I want to access like this
For example:
 http://163.54.69.96/var/www/html

for now error. (The requested URL /var/www/html was not found on this server.)

Comment: If the document root is /var/www/html you should access it with http://163.54.69.96, this shoul point to documents in the /var/www/html. Any other folder you add should be under /var/www/html, or configured in as a virtual host.

Comment: I added folder /var/www/html/1 but not worked. what do I do now? please tel me how can configured in as a virtual host.?